# Custom ImageView in android

Tags: android, image, imageview

I need help with the creation of an ImageView. I need to make an image with rounded edges, (a square with rounded edges). I don't know more exact word for it. Does anyone perhaps have code for it, or a link to a tutorial? Thanks in advance.

Example of ImageView:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Instead of rounding the imageview which is expensive, you should round the image itself then put the rounded image in the imageview with [RoundedBitmapDrawable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/graphics/drawable/RoundedBitmapDrawable.html)

example:

```
RoundedBitmapDrawable dr = RoundedBitmapDrawable.createRoundedBitmapDrawable(res, src);
dr.setCornerRadius(cornerRadius);

imageview.setImageDrawable(dr);
```

Comment: doesn't `RoundedBitmapDrawable` round the input Bitmap/Resource by itself?

Comment: @pskink I am not sure i understand what you mean. You give `RoundedBitmapDrawable.createRoundedBitmapDrawable` your bitmap with your corner radius and `getBitmap()` returns a Bitmap and you just set the imageview to that bitmap

Comment: you wrote "you **should round the image itself** then put the **rounded image** in the imageview with RoundedBitmapDrawable" so it suggests to pass "rounded" image to RoundedBitmapDrawable, btw `getBitmap()` returns original Bitmap/Resource, you should use that `RoundedBitmapDrawable` by calling `ImageView#setImageDrawable`

Comment: @pskink I added an example for clarification

Comment: see my comment above: "getBitmap() returns original Bitmap/Resource, you should use that RoundedBitmapDrawable by calling ImageView#setImageDrawable"

Comment: @pskink yes you are right I couldnt find my example I where I tried using it so I was going off the top of my head but I found it and yes you set the RoundedBitmapDrawable object itself

Comment: Actually  rounding the imageview isn't "expensive" at all, no extra resources are needed for that.  plus the time spent rounding an images corners is a time intensive process.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following class. The is an image view with rounded square boarders.

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.PorterDuff;
import android.graphics.PorterDuffXfermode;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.graphics.RectF;
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.widget.ImageView;

/**
 * A customized squared image view class.
 *
 * Extra functions:
 * {@link #removeBorder(boolean)}
 * {@link #setBorderWidth(int)}
 * {@link #setBorderColor(int)}
 * {@link @setBitmap}
 * <p/>
 * The rest of the things is exactly the same as {@link android.widget.ImageView}
 * <p/>
 * Created by amintavassolian on 15-02-12.
 */

public class SquareImageView extends ImageView {

    private static final float DEFAULT_BOARDER_STROKE = 5;

    private int borderColor;
    private int borderWidth;

    private Bitmap bitmap;

    private boolean removeBorder = false;

    public SquareImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

        Bitmap imageBitmap = getBitmapResource();
        Bitmap temporaryBitmap;
        if (imageBitmap != null) {
            temporaryBitmap = imageBitmap.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);
        } else {
            return;
        }

        int w = getWidth();

        Bitmap roundBitmap = getRoundedCroppedBitmap(cropBitmap(temporaryBitmap), w);
        canvas.drawBitmap(roundBitmap, 0, 0, null);
    }

    private Bitmap getBitmapResource() {
        if (bitmap == null) {
            Drawable drawable = getDrawable();
            if (drawable == null) {
                return null;
            }

            if (getWidth() == 0 || getHeight() == 0) {
                return null;
            }

            return ((BitmapDrawable) drawable).getBitmap();
        } else {
            return bitmap;
        }
    }

    private Bitmap cropBitmap(Bitmap sourceBmp) {
        Bitmap outputBmp;

        if (sourceBmp.getWidth() > sourceBmp.getHeight()) {
            outputBmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(sourceBmp, 0, 0, sourceBmp.getHeight(), sourceBmp.getHeight());
        } else if (sourceBmp.getWidth() < sourceBmp.getHeight()) {
            outputBmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(sourceBmp, 0, 0, sourceBmp.getWidth(), sourceBmp.getWidth());
        } else {
            outputBmp = sourceBmp;
        }

        return outputBmp;
    }

    private Bitmap getRoundedCroppedBitmap(Bitmap bitmap, int radius) {
        Bitmap finalBitmap;
        if (bitmap.getWidth() != radius || bitmap.getHeight() != radius) {
            // Set the filter to false, because we don't need very smooth one! It's cheaper!
            finalBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, radius, radius, false);
        } else {
            finalBitmap = bitmap;
        }

        Bitmap output = Bitmap.createBitmap(finalBitmap.getWidth(), finalBitmap.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(output);

        final Paint paint = new Paint();
        final Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, finalBitmap.getWidth(), finalBitmap.getHeight());

        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        paint.setFilterBitmap(true);
        paint.setDither(true);

        canvas.drawARGB(0, 0, 0, 0);

        // It doesn't matter which color!
        paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        canvas.drawRoundRect(new RectF(0, 0, finalBitmap.getWidth(), finalBitmap.getHeight()), 15, 15, paint);

        // The second drawing should only be visible of if overlapping with the first
        paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN));
        canvas.drawBitmap(finalBitmap, rect, rect, paint);

        // Draw the border, if exist
        if (!removeBorder) {
            canvas.drawRoundRect(new RectF(0, 0, finalBitmap.getWidth(), finalBitmap.getHeight()), 15, 15, getBorderPaint());
        }



        return output;
    }

    private Paint getBorderPaint() {
        Paint borderPaint = new Paint();
        if (borderColor != 0) {
            borderPaint.setColor(borderColor);
        } else {
            borderPaint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        }
        if (borderWidth != 0) {
            borderPaint.setStrokeWidth(borderWidth);
        } else {
            borderPaint.setStrokeWidth(DEFAULT_BOARDER_STROKE);
        }

        borderPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        borderPaint.setAntiAlias(true);

        return borderPaint;
    }

    /**
     * A method to set the bitmap for the image view
     *
     * @param bmp The target bitmap
     */
    public void setBitmap(Bitmap bmp) {
        this.bitmap = bmp;
    }

    /**
     * A method to se the color of the border of the image view
     *
     * @param colorResource The resource id of the favourite color
     */
    public void setBorderColor(int colorResource) {
        this.borderColor = colorResource;
    }

    /**
     * A method to set the thickness of the border of the image view
     *
     * @param width The width of the border stroke in pixels
     */
    public void setBorderWidth(int width) {
        this.borderWidth = width;
    }

    /**
     * A method to set whether show the image view with border or not
     *
     * @param removeBorder true to remove the border of the iamge view, otherwise it will have a border
     */
    public void removeBorder(boolean removeBorder) {
        this.removeBorder = removeBorder;
    }

}
```

You can simply put this in your xml layout and wither set the image by android:src attribute or invoke setBitmap() function. You can customize this border of the iamgeview by calling the following functions in your code as well:

```
setBorderColor(int colorResource)
setBorderWidth(int width)
removeBorder(boolean removeBorder)
```

Here is an example of the xml layout:

```
<yourpackagename.SquareImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/sample_image" />
```

**UPDATE**
As @pskink has suggested you can use RoundedBitmap as well. I was not familiar with that class. However, this above class still gives you some extra features.

Cheers
A.

Comment: better use `RoundedBitmapDrawable`

Answer (score 0):

Metalink, 
This is how I round off my image's edges, add the following code in your image's XML.

```
<ImageView
    android:bottomRightRadius="20dip"
    android:bottomLeftRadius="20dip"  
    android:topRightRadius="20dip"
    android:topLeftRadius="20dip"
```

/>

Depending on the size of your Image size, increase or decrease the dip's to 10/30 accordingly.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to border affects the image, use this class. Unfortunately, I didn't find any approach to draw a transparent area on the canvas came to onDraw(). So, here is created a new bitmap and it's drawn on a real canvas.

The view is useful if you want to make a disappearing border. If you set borderWidth to 0, the border will disappear and the image remains with rounder corners exactly like the border was. I.e. it looks like the border is drawn exactly by the image edges.

```
import android.annotation.SuppressLint
import android.content.Context
import android.graphics.Bitmap
import android.graphics.Canvas
import android.graphics.Color
import android.graphics.Paint
import android.graphics.PorterDuff
import android.graphics.PorterDuffXfermode
import android.graphics.RectF
import android.util.AttributeSet
import androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView


class RoundedImageViewWithBorder @JvmOverloads constructor(
        context: Context,
        attrs: AttributeSet? = null,
        defStyleAttr: Int = 0) : AppCompatImageView(context, attrs, defStyleAttr) {

    var borderColor: Int = 0
        set(value) {
            invalidate()
            field = value
        }
    var borderWidth: Int = 0
        set(value) {
            invalidate()
            field = value
        }
    var cornerRadius: Float = 0f
        set(value) {
            invalidate()
            field = value
        }

    private var bitmapForDraw: Bitmap? = null
    private var canvasForDraw: Canvas? = null
    private val transparentPaint = Paint().apply {
        isAntiAlias = true
        color = Color.TRANSPARENT
        style = Paint.Style.STROKE
        xfermode = PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.SRC)
    }

    private val borderPaint = Paint().apply {
        isAntiAlias = true
        style = Paint.Style.STROKE
    }

    private val transparentAreaRect = RectF()
    private val borderRect = RectF()

    init {
        val typedArray = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.RoundedImageViewWithBorder)

        try {
            borderWidth = typedArray.getDimensionPixelSize(R.styleable.RoundedImageViewWithBorder_border_width, 0)
            borderColor = typedArray.getColor(R.styleable.RoundedImageViewWithBorder_border_color, 0)
            cornerRadius = typedArray.getDimensionPixelSize(R.styleable.RoundedImageViewWithBorder_corner_radius, 0).toFloat()

        } finally {
            typedArray.recycle()
        }
    }

    @SuppressLint("CanvasSize", "DrawAllocation")
    override fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas) {

        if (canvasForDraw?.height != canvas.height || canvasForDraw?.width != canvas.width) {
            val newBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(canvas.width, canvas.height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)
            bitmapForDraw = newBitmap
            canvasForDraw = Canvas(newBitmap)
        }

        // Draw existing content
        super.onDraw(canvasForDraw)

        if (borderWidth > 0) {
            canvasForDraw?.let { drawWithBorder(it) }
        } else {
            canvasForDraw?.let { drawWithoutBorder(it) }
        }

        // Draw everything on real canvas
        bitmapForDraw?.let { canvas.drawBitmap(it, 0f, 0f, null) }
    }

    private fun drawWithBorder(canvas: Canvas) {
        // Draw transparent area
        transparentPaint.strokeWidth = borderWidth.toFloat() * 4
        transparentAreaRect.apply {
            left = -borderWidth.toFloat() * 1.5f
            top = -borderWidth.toFloat() * 1.5f
            right = canvas.width.toFloat() + borderWidth.toFloat() * 1.5f
            bottom = canvas.height.toFloat() + borderWidth.toFloat() * 1.5f
        }
        canvasForDraw?.drawRoundRect(transparentAreaRect, borderWidth.toFloat() * 2 + cornerRadius, borderWidth.toFloat() * 2 + cornerRadius, transparentPaint)

        // Draw border
        borderPaint.color = borderColor
        borderPaint.strokeWidth = borderWidth.toFloat()
        borderRect.apply {
            left = borderWidth.toFloat() / 2
            top = borderWidth.toFloat() / 2
            right = canvas.width.toFloat() - borderWidth.toFloat() / 2
            bottom = canvas.height.toFloat() - borderWidth.toFloat() / 2
        }
        canvas.drawRoundRect(borderRect, cornerRadius - borderWidth.toFloat() / 2, cornerRadius - borderWidth.toFloat() / 2, borderPaint)
    }

    private fun drawWithoutBorder(canvas: Canvas) {
        // Draw transparent area
        transparentPaint.strokeWidth = cornerRadius * 4
        transparentAreaRect.apply {
            left = -cornerRadius * 2
            top = -cornerRadius * 2
            right = canvas.width.toFloat() + cornerRadius * 2
            bottom = canvas.height.toFloat() + cornerRadius * 2
        }
        canvasForDraw?.drawRoundRect(transparentAreaRect, cornerRadius * 3, cornerRadius * 3, transparentPaint)
    }

}
```

In values:

```
<declare-styleable name="RoundedImageViewWithBorder">
    <attr name="corner_radius" format="dimension|string" />
    <attr name="border_width" format="dimension|reference" />
    <attr name="border_color" format="color|reference" />
</declare-styleable>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use cardview then set radius to cardview

for example

```
 <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                            android:layout_width="80dp"
                            android:layout_height="80dp"

                            android:layout_gravity="center"
                            app:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
                            >
                
                            <ImageView
                                android:id="@+id/test"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                android:src="@drawable/logo"
                               />
                       
                        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```